# How to use gTTS in python?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, attributeerror, google-text-to-speech

When executing the below code

```
 from gtts import gTTS
 tts = gTTS('hello')
 tts.save('hello.mp3')
```

I am getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'".

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Desktop\programming\Python_code\New Text Document - Copy (8) - Copy.py", line 3, in <module>
    tts.save('hello.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 247, in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 187, in write_to_fp
    part_tk = self.token.calculate_token(part)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 28, in calculate_token
    seed = self._get_token_key()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 62, in _get_token_key
    a = re.search("a\\\\x3d(-?\d+);", tkk_expr).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Is it possible to use gTTS in Python?

Comment: I'm also getting this error starting today, I've been using gtts in python no problem for a while now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an official fix now. It had to do with an upstream dependency of gtts, [gtts-token](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS-token/). It has been fixed in gtts-token==1.1.2

My issue was fixed after I did a fresh install of both gtts and gtts-token.

The relevant github issue in gtts can be found [here](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/137). Amazing this issue was fixed in 12 hours. Praise the open source gods! :D

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code on line 64 of gtts_token.py, and I tried to `print(a)`, but it shows "NoneType".

I repaired that bug in line 64:

```
# bug
# a = re.search(“a\\\\x3d(-?\d+);”, tkk_expr).group(1)
# b = re.search(“b\\\\x3d(-?\d+);”, tkk_expr).group(1)

# debug
tkk = tkk_expr.replace(“\’”, “”).split(“;”)[0].split(“=”)[1]
a = tkk.split(“.”)[0]
b = tkk.split(“.”)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall both gtts-token and gtts and install them again.

```
pip uninstall gtts-token
pip uninstall gtts
pip install gtts-token
pip install gtts
```